# QPickPointEvent when mouse cursor do something above points in Python Qt 3D?

Tags: pyqt5, qt3d, pyside2

I have a `QEntity` with a mesh which is set as a primitive type (Points). Beside that I also initialized `QObjectPicker` and connect four basic signals to functions (`clicked`, `moved`, `pressed`, and `released`). When I run application and do some mouse events, none of these events  is `QPickPointEvent`. Only `QPickEvent`s occur. Is it possible in Python to trigger a `QPickPointEvent`?

I also set pick method to `PointPicking`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable point picking using the pick method on the QPickSettings property of the instance of QRenderSettings.

In that case, the QPickEvent will actually be an instance of QPointPickEvent. I'm not sure how you "downcast" that in python though.

But if you entity is indeed using point primitives, then the coordinates of the picked point and the point itself should be the same. The only information you would be missing is the index of the point in it's parent list of primitives.

Comment: Thanks! `PointPicking` now works and I get instances of `QPointPickEvent`. No need to downcast in Python.